# In my 2d game, the camera is moving 1 extra pixel each time the player is at the left or the right limit of the screen

Tags: java, camera, 2d

Please excuse my bad english. I am having a problem while implementing a 2d camera. I made the camera to follow the player until it reaches near the edge of the game-level, where only the player moves and the camera stops. I made this easily but my problem is that the camera is not proper. The camera continues to move 1 extra pixel every time you reach at the edge of the game-level limit in all four directions (The code I posted only shows horizontal movement. This I did for simplicity). This means if you move 40 times to and fro near the left edge of the game, camera will move 40 extra pixels right! I have no idea how to solve this. 
I posted a very simplified version from my original code below and made it as small as i could to show how the program works. Following just moves the player and camera horizontally across the screen.

*This is 'theGamePanel' class (it is the main class) :-*

```
public class TheGamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener 
{
    private boolean left, right;
    private float cameraX, cameraY;
    private World world = new World();
    private Player player = new Player();

    public TheGamePanel() 
    {   
        //setting the size of panel
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //setting the window
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        // drawing the game-level and player
        g.translate((int)cameraX, (int)cameraY);
        world.paint(g);
        player.paint(g);
        g.translate(-(int)cameraX, -(int)cameraY);
    }

    public void upd() 
    {
        player.update(left, right, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // game-loop
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            left = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        {
            right = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        {
            right = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    //to set camera position
    public void setCameraX(float cameraDx) 
    {
        cameraX += cameraDx;
    }
}
```

*This is the 'Player' class. This class is where the player and camera movement takes place. The camera's x and values are then returned to 'TheGamePanel' :-*

```
public class Player 
{
    private float x, y;
    private float dx = 1;
    private int width = 32, height = 32;
    private float leftLimit, rightLimit;

    public Player() 
    {
        //player's initial x and y coordinates
        x = 320;
        y = 240;
        //camera's limit (where the camera needs to stop following player)
        leftLimit = x;
        rightLimit = 960;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        //for painting the player
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, width, height);
    }

    //to move player and camera
    public void update(boolean left, boolean right, TheGamePanel panel) 
    {
        if(left == true) 
        {
            x -= dx;
            if(x > leftLimit && x < rightLimit) 
            {
                panel.setCameraX(dx);
            }
        }
        if(right == true) 
        {
            x += dx;
            if(x > leftLimit && x < rightLimit) 
            {
                panel.setCameraX(-dx);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*And lastly, the 'World' class. This class is used to simply paint a big map(level) in the background :-*

```
public class World 
{   
    private BufferedImage map;
    private int tileWd = 32, tileHi = 32;

    public World() 
    {
        try 
        {
            map = ImageIO.read(new File("map1.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        //simply paints a game-level in the background
    }
}
```

If anything not understandable please tell. I will add more details.

Comment: Your code allows both left and right to be true at the same time. It's true that the player can have both buttons pressed at the same time, but I think you should manually disable left when right is pressed and vice versa. `TheGamePanel.keyPressed`

Comment: @David I have checked both, but none solved the actual problem of camera.

Comment: `panel.setCameraX(0);` does nothing, you could remove it to make the code easier to read.

Comment: @David Oh yes you are right. that else statements are useless

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where the player is standing near the right edge of the map. One quick tap on the "right" key moves him out of the camera-follow area so the camera doesn't move. One quick tap on the "left" key moves him back into the camera-follow area. The camera will be moved "dx" units to the left. This will have the effect of the player slowly creeping closer to the right edge of the playing field, if I'm correct.

(To find bugs like this, I generally litter the code with `System.out.println` messages. If there's a lot of messages, I write them to a file and do text searches on keywords)

Comment: yes. the entire map is slowly creeping to an edge 1 pixel at a time. how can i remove this bug

Comment: Instead of moving the camera `dx` steps every time the player moves `dx` steps, I would recalculate the camera position from scratch based on the player position. If the player is outside the camera-follow area, use the edge coordinate instead of the player coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

you have a location for your camera (cameraX,cameraY) but nothing for the player?

just create a location for player (playerX,playerY)

change the paint like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paint(g);
    // drawing the game-level and player
    g.translate((int)cameraX, (int)cameraY);
    world.paint(g);
    g.translate((int)playerX, (int)playerY);
    player.paint(g);
    g.translate(-(int)(playerX+cameraX), -(int)(playerY+cameraY));
}
```

and when player come near borders don't move camera and only player.

Comment: how is this method different from my method

Comment: the part `g.translate((int)playerX, (int)playerY);` moves player inside scene.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following change fixes the problem:

*Player class*:

```
//to move player and camera
public void update(boolean left, boolean right, TheGamePanel panel) 
{
    if(left == true) 
    {
        x -= dx;
        if(x > leftLimit && x < rightLimit) 
        {
            panel.setCameraX(dx);
        }
    }
    if(right == true) 
    {
        if(x > leftLimit && x < rightLimit) 
        {
            panel.setCameraX(-dx);
        }
        x += dx;     // Only change: moved this line AFTER the if block
    }
}
```

By testing x after changing it when moving left and before changing it when moving right you compensate for the error that was otherwise accumulating every time you reached one of the boundaries.

Anyway I suggest you to change your approach to the problem in order to make your code easier to maintain and more flexible. One way to do that is to calculate the camera position based on current player's position on every frame.

**Note:** The line `g.translate(-(int)cameraX, -(int)cameraY);` in the `paint()` method of TheGamePanel class is unnecessary once the method `translate(int, int)` is not incremental.

Regards